# Simultaneous Animation For Same Element in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image in a canvas. What I want to do is code an animation which both rotates the image 90 degrees and move the image from the top left corner of canvas to the bottom right corner at the same time to create an action looks like projectile motion. However, I could only manage to do one part of the animation so far.

```
DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 90, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
image.RenderTransform = rt;
rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotateAnimation);

TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
image.RenderTransform = tt;
DoubleAnimation moveXAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 300, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
DoubleAnimation moveYAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 300, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
tt.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, moveXAnimation);
tt.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, moveYAnimation);
```

These two blocks works very well separately, but do not work together(consequently). The latter one works only. Anyone can tell me why?

UPDATE (Complete answer of Clemens):

```
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 90, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));

TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
DoubleAnimation moveXAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 300, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
DoubleAnimation moveYAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 300, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

TransformGroup transform = new TransformGroup();
transform.Children.Add(rt);
transform.Children.Add(tt);
image.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
image.RenderTransform = transform;

rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotateAnimation);
tt.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, moveXAnimation);
tt.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, moveYAnimation);
```

Comment: `image` and `target` are the same element?

Comment: yup, i corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put both transforms in a TransformGroup, and assign that to the image's RenderTransform:

```
var rt = new RotateTransform();
var tt = new TranslateTransform();
var transform = new TransformGroup();
transform.Children.Add(rt);
transform.Children.Add(tt);
image.RenderTransform = transform;

// run animations
```

You may also want to take a look at how to use a [Path Animation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970561.aspx) for a more realistic look. The projectile might follow a parabolic curve.

Comment: I will add the complete solution to my question.